# How to remove "_www" user from the everyone group?

Tags: permission, user-account, apache, group

As the question said: How do I remove the `_www` user form the everyone group?

**Background:** I am trying to lock down PHP to my web directory. PHP runs under the `_www` user. My solution is to only give read permission to the web directory, but since `_www` is part of the everyone group it is become a big hassle.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how the group everyone is a hassle? It mainly exists as a group identified in access control entries which deny the current user belonging to the group everyone from unlinking directories.

Comment: @fd0  Long story short, currently using injection like `/./././` as user can get out of the web directory and access the entire file system. If _www doesn’t have permission outside of the web directory then it’s not a problem because they will get a Forbidden header. Unfortunately, Everyone has access to some files in the user home folder therefore _www can access these folders. I don’t want to remove the everyone group because I want others to be able to access it. “A hassle” because I would be required to add every user individually instead of using the everyone group.

Comment: @fd0 Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that Apple uses the name `everyone` instead of `others` in the last traditional permission class? The classifications in traditional file permissions would be `user/owner`, `group`, then `others`. Apple has used `others`, `everybody` and `everyone` , depending on the OS version.

Comment: @fd0 I wasn't but now I am aware :) But how does that change anything?

Comment: Well, is the group `everyone` or the classification `everyone` the problem? I haven't setup a web server in almost a decade but can't you configure the web server to stay in the document root?

Comment: @fd0 I don't get the first question.  Yes, there is a way to configure it this way but it is better practice to rely on the OS.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I have in my /etc/group file:
_www:*:70:_devicemgr,_teamsserver

and

everyone:*:12:
This means there's no user in everyone group, and _devicemgr and _teamserver are in group _www

If you have _www user in everyone group (ie in everyone line), you have to remove it from everyone group (the second line)

user needs to login to see effect. Reboot is easyer.

Comment: I have `_www:*:70:_devicemgr,_teamsserver` & `everyone:*:12:`. According to Directory Utility, everyone group is calculated by the system.

Comment: So _www is NOT in everyone group. You can't remove it.

Comment: It **is** in the `everyone` group. Check out this answer/script : https://superuser.com/a/395738

Comment: Go back to your initial need. What gives the command "ls -l" (in a terminal) on one of your web directories ?

Comment: I don't think you understand. There are many folders in which `everyone` has read access. This includes `_www`. I don't want `_www` to access, therefore I need to remove `_www` from the `everyone` group

Comment: If you don't want group members to have read access, you can either remove _www from everyone group, or remove read access to group and others. That's why I asked you the result of "ls -l". In fact only user, group, read and write acces are necessary to understand what you have. Ex: to remove read access to grou and other, you can use "chmod go-rx the_top_directory". Thus no group members, and no one else can read any of the_top_directory and sub-directories.

Comment: Yes this is true, but I do not want to remove `Everyone`. There are members of `Everyone` that I want to have access. It is just `_www` I don't.